# ListView + POCO

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Can I somehow use POCOs in a ListView? Or are ListViewItem's my only option?

If I can only use ListViewItems is it possible to assign a value object (my POCO) or is it possible to use subitems with value objects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) which plays very nicely with POCOs.

[image: ObjectListView rendering pipeline]

**Update**

**ObjectListView** is based on the regular ListView, but it uses some magic and the win32 api to make everything possible. It's not very hard to get started with it and I don't really see why you can't use it?

**Standard listview**: All options (except owner drawing) include using a ListViewItem. If you got a large collection I recommend that you use Virtual Mode which means that the list view will request each item that is visible.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice option but I'd rather stick with the original framework. Can you be more precise about what concerns my question?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem class Tag and Text work fine for me. No Pocos though, but I can keep the original values in their original data types.